# How to add a control to a input file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to require an input of type file using `angularjs` without using the attribute `required` in the `HTML` code.
My interface is : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xobq.png)

I want to get an alert after hitting the button `submit`.

This is what I have done : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlwGv.png)

```
function DatabaseCtrl($scope, $http, predefineds, locationSearch, queries, database, $window) {
var credentials = {
fileName: ""
};
$scope.credentials = credentials;
$scope.uploadToFolder = function() {
    if( $scope.credentials.fileName.length<1 ) {
        $window.alert("Please select a file!");
        return false;
    }
    database.uploadToFolder($scope.credentials.fileName, true);
};
```

The HTML code :

```
        <form role="form" name="frmUploadFolder" ng-submit="uploadToFolder()">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>
            <span ng-show="isUserFile">File directory browser :</span>
            <button type="button" ng-show="isUserFile" class="btn btn-default">See file(s)</button>
            <button type="button" ng-show="!isUserFile" class="btn btn-default">Upload file(s)</button>
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                <label ng-show="isUserFile" >Please specify a file, or a set of files:</label><br>
                <input type="file" ng-show="isUserFile" name="datafile" id="fileName" ng-model="credentials.fileName" size="20" required multiple>
                <button type="submit" ng-show="isUserFile" class="btn btn-default" >Upload</button><br>
            </p>

        <div ui-if="!tree.length" class="message">
            <p ui-if="!tree.loading">
                <span ng-show="!isUserFile">Empty directory</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The service js :

```
angular.module('referl.services').factory('database', function($http, channel, $rootScope) {
var database = {
    uploadToFolder: function(fileName, navigateOnSuccess) {
        var parameters = {
            fileName: fileName

        };
        $http.get("api/database/uploadToFolder", {params: parameters})
            .success(function(response) {
                if(response.error) {
                    alert(response.error);
                } else {
                    if (navigateOnSuccess) {
                        alert("Navigation On Success !");
                    }
                }
            });

    }

};
```

Any help please?

Comment: Post the HTML code as well.

Comment: Implement a custom directive, `file-model`, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm for an example.

Comment: http://localhost:8001/api/database/uploadToFolder Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason angular does not fully support binding a model element to a file input. The directive approach is generally the accepted work around, but within your controller you can also use document.getElementById("filename") to get a reference to the filename input and grab its value.